# How to set the browser title to the active user control in a Silverlight Application

Tags: c#, silverlight, navigation, browser

I've a Silverlight application (uses Silverlight 3 in VS 2010 proffessional) running from the browser. The application does navigation from one user control to another. I need my browser to change its title to the name of the page it got navigated to. As of now I wrote a javascript like this:

```
    HtmlPage.Window.Eval("new function(){document.title='" + this.GetType().Name + "'}");
```

This works perfectly fine. But is any better alternatives than this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
HtmlPage.Document.SetProperty("title", this.GetType().Name);
```